# Get Equirectangular Video in Youtube for 4K MP4

Tags: c#, youtube

I'm using a C# WebClient() to request videos from Youtube.

When I don't pass a user-agent to the web client, I get 360 videos in equirectangular projection. I find it in the source code of the page.

Youtube only serves 4K video in WebM format(Youtube, internally calls it format 313). I don't get any 4K video in MP4. The highest resolution for an MP4 video is 2K.

When I pass a user-agent of any PC browser (say Chrome or Firefox), Youtube sends a 4K video in MP4. But then it uses a weird 3x2 cubemap projection. 
[image: 3x2 cubemap]

Is there a way I can get 4K MP4 video with equirectangular projection?
*The format I'm looking for is 266.

Answer (score 5):

You can encode it to Equirectangular using the v360 video filter:

```sh
ffmpeg \
-i input.mkv \
-vf "v360=c3x2:e:cubic:in_forder='lfrdbu':in_frot='000313',scale=3840:1920,setsar=1:1" \
-c:v libx264 \
-preset faster \
-crf 21 \
-c:a copy \
-movflags +faststart \
output.mp4
```

This command already has the face order of YouTube's cube map and the rotation of the faces, the final filter scales it to an equirectangular 4K-UHD video.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube have change the 360 video format as a new format.(called the Equi-Angular Cubemap, or EAC).
https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/15267

Thus,you can not get 4k Equirectangular video from youtube now.

You can try to get 4k Equirectangular video from other website, such as Vimeo .
https://www.mettle.com/360vr-master-series-free-360-downloads-page/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19543260)

Comment: Well, you have improved your text but I think that it doesn't answer the question, does it? "Is there a way I can get 4K MP4 video with equirectangular projection?"

Comment: Got it.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is low tech and doesn't yet render the audio. I made a Blender file that projects the movie onto the inside of a cube, and renders it with an equirectangular camera. It's slow but the quality is OK.

Update: I've now somewhat corrected for the distortion Google applies (equi-angular projection) which they did to improve overall resolution. Pixels get moved from far-away corners to the middle of the faces, where most of the viewing is done.

[image: The important bits of my Blender file]

Here's the file: https://jacobbruinsma.com/resources/youTube360toEquirect.zip

You can merge video and audio with ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -i audiofile.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy outfile.mp4`

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Comment: Done, I updated my post. I'll mention this just in case, I'm not going to provide a whole Blender tutorial here. There are millions of videos on that subject available and this isn't the right place for it.